# Clone and fix banner with jQuery/ES5

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, refactoring, ecmascript-5

I have to improve my code, especially looking for performance (in this project I can use jQuery and ES5).

What I want to achieve is that I have to mark the banner (injected from the external website) and when the banner hides after scrolling, then a smaller version will flow smoothly, and when the window reaches its top, it will be fixed to the top.

What I managed to do is that [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kruzyk/kt7fahr3/39/):

```
var bannerDA = $('div[class*="-a--katalog"]');
var bannerClone = $();
var clone = $();
var CLONE_HEIGHT = 100;
var bannerDABottom = bannerDA.offset().top + 200;       // bannerDA.height() not working for iframe ??

$(document).ready(function() {
    if (bannerDA.length !== 0) {
        $(window).on('scroll', function() {
            if ($(window).scrollTop() > bannerDABottom && bannerClone.length == 0) {
                bannerClone = bannerDA.clone()
                // avoid paragraphs and insert before first div:
                .insertBefore('.subcontent-body div:eq(0)') 
                .addClass('clone')
                .animate({height: CLONE_HEIGHT}, 500);               
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= bannerDABottom && bannerClone.length > 0) {
                bannerClone.animate({height: '0'}, 200, function() {
                    bannerClone.remove();
                    bannerClone = $();
                });
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() > bannerClone.offset().top && clone.length == 0) { 
                clone = bannerClone.clone()
                                   .css('opacity', '1')
                                   .css('height', CLONE_HEIGHT)
                                   .appendTo('.subcontent-body')
                                   .addClass('clone--fixed');
            } else if ($(window).scrollTop() <= bannerClone.offset().top && clone.length > 0) {
                clone.remove();
                clone = $();
            }
        }).trigger('scroll');
    }
});
```

**How I can refactor it?**

*/edited:*

Is it a good practice to create an empty jQuery object when declaring variables? // I'm doing this to be able to check if the object exists (length).

Maybe it would be better to clone a banner once and then just show it and hide it, instead of processing everything on scrolls?

Should I clone a banner twice? Maybe there should be one copy, static or fixed depending on the scrollTop. How can you prevent the page from jumping?

After many attempts I managed to write a similarly working code but it does not work in 100% as I want and I have no idea if it is more effective:
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kruzyk/kt7fahr3/45/). **Should I provide more information?** I am waiting for your help.

Comment: I managed to write some code but it does not work the way I want it and I have no idea if it is more effective: [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kruzyk/kt7fahr3/44/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from friend this is solution:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var bannerDA = $('div[class*="-a--katalog"]');
  var bannerClone = $();
  var clone = $();
  var CLONE_HEIGHT = 100;

  if (bannerDA.length !== 0) {

    const bannerDABottom = bannerDA.offset().top + 200; // bannerDA.height() not working for iframe ??

    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
      const scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

      if (scrollTop > bannerDABottom && bannerClone.length === 0) {
        bannerClone = bannerDA.clone()
          // avoid paragraphs and insert before first div:
          .insertBefore('.subcontent-body div:eq(0)')
          .addClass('clone')
          .animate({
            height: CLONE_HEIGHT
          }, 500);
        return;
      }

      if (scrollTop <= bannerDABottom && bannerClone.length > 0) {
        bannerClone.animate({
          height: '0'
        }, 200, function() {
          bannerClone.remove();
          bannerClone = $();
        });
        return;
      }

      if (scrollTop > bannerClone.offset().top && clone.length === 0) {
        clone = bannerClone.clone()
          .css('opacity', '1')
          .css('height', CLONE_HEIGHT)
          .appendTo('.subcontent-body')
          .addClass('clone--fixed');
        return;
      }

      if (scrollTop <= bannerClone.offset().top && clone.length > 0) {
        clone.remove();
        clone = $();
        return;
      }
    }).trigger('scroll');
  }
});
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kruzyk/kt7fahr3/46/)